# как изменить состояние другого компонента в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть два компонента

первый

```
class AddRecipe extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: this.props.show}
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.show) {
            return (
                <div className="add-area"></div>
            )
        }
        else 
            return(<nothing />)
    }
}
```

второй

```
class Project extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.changeShowAddArea = this.changeShowAddArea.bind(this);
        this.state = {showAddArea: false};
    }
    changeShowAddArea() {
        this.setState({
            showAddArea: true
        })

    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <RecipeArea />
                <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.changeShowAddArea} id="add">
                    Add a recipe
                </Button>
                <AddRecipe show={this.state.showAddArea}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

когда нажимаю на кнопку this.state.showAddArea меняется, но AddRecipe не показывается, как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно пропсы копировать в state

```
class AddRecipe extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (this.props.show) {
            return (
                <div className="add-area"></div>
            )
        }
        else 
            return null;
    }
}
```

А если уж скопировали, то их нужно своевременно обновлять в `componentWillReciveProps`.

Comment: спасибо! только начинаю изучать реакт и с этими componentWill.. componentDid... проблемки

Comment: @epsilon в данном случае они вам и не нужны, используйте props напрямую.